# best way to add and delete text lines with jquery product configurator

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am creating a product configurator with Jquery. My users can add custom text lines to their product. So you could create say... 4 text lines with custom text.

I need to know what the best way to add and delete these lines would be. Currently I have the following code for adding lines...

```
    //Add Text Button
$('a#addText').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Scroll up the text editor
    $('.textOptions').slideUp();
    $('#customText').val('');

    //count how many items are in the ul textList
    var textItems = $('ul#textList li').size();
    var nextNumber = textItems + 1;

    if(textItems <= 5) {

        //Change input to reflect current text being changed
        $('input#currentTextNumber').val(nextNumber);

        //Append a UL Item to the textList
        $('ul#textList').append('<li id="textItem'+nextNumber+'">Text Line. +$5.00 <a class="deleteTextItem" href="'+nextNumber+'">Delete</a></li>');

        //Scroll down the text editor
        $('.textOptions').slideDown();

    }else {

        alert('you can have a maximum of 6 textual inputs!');   

    }
});
```

I'm probably not doing this the best way, but basically i have an empty UL list to start with. So when they click "Add Text Line" it finds  out how many list elements are in the unordered list, adds a value of 1 to that and places a new list element with the id TextItem1 or TextItem2 or whatever number we're on.

The problem i'm running into is that when you click delete item, it screws everything up because when you add an item again all the numbers aren't correct. I thought about writing some kind of logic that says all the numbers above the one you want deleted get 1 subtracted from their value and all the numbers below stay the same. But I think i'm just going about this the wrong way.

Any suggestions on the easiest way to add and delete these text lines is appreciated.

Comment: are the lines being sent to the server in some shape or form?

Comment: do the ID numbers matter  before user is finished? Like with the "delete" sending ajax. If not you can move completely away from  ID's and use common classes

Comment: Thats my train of thought, im thinking he could acquire line numbers based on the order of the items.  doing so would involve iterating through them, and assigning IDs upon the formulation of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to increment ID's or classes in a situation where you will be adding and removing random ones is usually more of a headache than it is worth

Change to a single class for the items

```
<li class="textItem">
```

Your delete would look like

```
$('#textList').on('click','.textItem a', function(){/* note that live() is deprecated*/
      $(this).parent().remove();
      $('input#currentTextNumber').val( $('#textList li').length );/* note that size() is deprecated*/
      return false;
});
```

If you have any other dynamic data storage or AJAX going on with server within any of this process there are likely simple ways to configure those too in conjunction with using common class for elements.

Comment: Please have a look at the site where I have uploaded it so you can see why i'm using ID's. I need the text draggable like I have it. I can't think of the best way to implement what I'm trying to do. It works till you start deleting things

Comment: found the draggable on the image..font was really small. You can use `index()` method to remove . Ill put very simple demo together

Comment: Thank you that would be most helpful. This is destroying my brain cells. lol.

Comment: here's a demo using index ... no ID's http://jsfiddle.net/jEBKL/ If you aren't using sortable , just draggable, this concept should be enough to manage deletes.

Comment: I think this is the best way to go I just need to wrap my head around how i'm going to implement it in my project. Thanks for the demo. helps alot.

Comment: So how would I add an item if the add button does not come from within the list? I have your code up at: http://faithpointdallas.com/ecom/page/customStole

Comment: When starting out with jQuery..ID selectors seem like the simplest way to go. But in dynamic situations, as you are finding out, there are easier paths to travel. It's a matter of learning traversal methods that involve bigger learning curve..good luck

Comment: Add the same way you were, just don't need to use the incremental ID's and change to using classes. There are some more advanced concepts also like binding events but hard to teach in a comment box

Comment: Hey man, this COMPLETELY helped me get this part. I have it working 100% on: http://faithpointdallas.com/ecom/pages/customStole

Thanks for the help this helps me be able to move on. I have ALOT to learn about doing custom things like this but to me, the best way to learn is to dive in and learn as you go. Same way I learned PHP, AJAX, HTML, CSS, everything. lol.

Comment: Would you recommend any good books that explain concepts like you mentioned that would help me in the future on projects like this?

Comment: I am completely self taught from the internet in everything to do with web or any programming. Bookmarking the API and wandering through the various methods and great examples is how I learned the most...and following forums like this. http://api.jquery.com/. You can google search some pretty good tutorials also

Comment: Yeah I'm self taught as well. Started 7 years ago freelancing in standard xhtml and css. Taught myself PHP about 3 years ago. Discovered codeigniter and since then i've got some really crazy projects under my belt. lol.

Comment: similar.. I like php but I really like front end..more visual

Comment: @charlietfl: this was helpful. I didn't use .eq(rowIndex) before because I was always relying on id/class/tag references. Obviously sometimes this can make things more simple.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

EDIT: Obviously references are something I should have taken into account. 
Code was working, but without wanted references.
Well, then use this...

```
var currentIdx = $('ul#textList li').size();

$('a#addText').click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();

    //Scroll up the text editor
    $('.textOptions').slideUp();

    //count how many items are in the ul textList
    var nextNumber = currentIdx++;

    if($('ul#textList li').size() <= 5) {

        //Change input to reflect current text being changed
        $('input#currentTextNumber').val(nextNumber);

        var newLi = $('<li class="textItem' + nextNumber + '">' + 
            $('#customText').val() +
            '<a class="deleteTextItem" href="#">Delete</a></li>');

        newLi.find('a.deleteTextItem').click(function() {
            $(this).parent('li').remove();
        })

        //Append a UL Item to the textList
        $('ul#textList').append(newLi);

        $('#customText').val('');

        //Scroll down the text editor
        $('.textOptions').slideDown();

    } else {
        alert('you can have a maximum of 6 textual inputs!');   
    }
});​
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozrentk/JFagb/3/).

Comment: how does this make any difference to the increment problem OP already has?

Comment: I think "Any suggestions on the easiest way to add and delete these text lines is appreciated." is clear enough.

Comment: agree..if it resolves a problem, but you have the same increment duplication issue that OP does and haven't provided any feedback regarding what your code solves

Comment: I implemented your code and it works for the list items but I guess I didn't mention that when they type in the text it creates a div on the right side of the page that is draggable called #textDrag1, #textDrag2 etc. THAT is where my problem is coming in. It deletes the list item but when it deletes the corresponding #textDrag div, it screws up when you add another input. I am uploading what I have to a server for you to view.

Comment: @charlietfl - I understand, references were issue as well, so I updated the code

Comment: Here is the site online so you can see how it is messing up:

http://faithpointdallas.com/ecom/page/customStole

Comment: What happens is that at first there is empty line added, because input textbox is hidden. After that, when I delete textbox, draggable layer is not deleted. Should that happen, or...?

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. Use my updated script (you used old one in your site) that updates $('input#currentTextNumber').val(currentNum). Sorry, last time I forgot to update fiddler link :(